# Function does return null when return value is of enum type

Tags: java, mockito

I'm writing a unit test for a function in a `TestClass`, which checks an `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.Cell`'s contents and returns enum type. Enum is the following:

```
public enum Enum_1 {
  SKIP,
  EXIT_1,
  EXIT_2
}
```

And here's the function:

```
public ENUM_1 check (Cell cell, String str, int someInt) {
  String cellValue = new String(cell.getValueArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  if(//case 1, doesn't fall here) {
      /.../
      return SKIP;
  }
  else if(//case 2, doesn't fall here neither){
      /.../
      return EXIT_1;
  }
  //100% sure falls in this case
  else {
      Long long1 = getLong(str, someInt);
      Long long2 = Long.parseLong(cellValue);
      if(long1 > long2) {
        return EXIT_2;
      }
  }
  return SKIP;
}
```

In unit test, i use mockito to make function `getLong(str, someInt)` return certain value. Unit test code looks like so:

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    TestClass testClass = mock(TestClass.class);
    Cell mockCell = mock(Cell.class);
    String str = "str";
    int someInt = 1;
    when(mockCell.getValueArray()).thenReturn("500".getBytes());
    when(testClass.getLong(same(str), same(someInt)).thenReturn(Long.valueOf(400));

    TestClass.ENUM_1 result = testClass.check(mockCell, str, someInt);
    assertEquals(result, TestClass.ENUM_1.SKIP);
}
```

But when i run the test, it falis due to `result` being `null`.

Again, i'm 100% sure the passed value in `else{}` case in function `check()`.

The question is: why am i getting `null` from a function with return value of ENUM type? Is there something i did wrong with Mockito? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Because you are mocking the _class under test_, which - by the way - is very bad practice.

Comment: As Seelenvirtuose said, you should not mock the classes that need to be tested, ie `TestClass `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why am i getting null from a function with return value of ENUM type?

You're getting null because the method called returned null.  Enums are not a special type in this respect; enum references can be null just as any other object references can be.

> Is this something i did wrong with Mockito?

Yes.

It looks like you mocked out the *class you're testing*, which is almost certainly not what you want to do (because then you're not testing the code in the real class).  You then defined a stub return for the `getLong()` method, but didn't tell the mock anything about the `check()` method.

Thus, when you called `testClass.check(mockCell, str, someInt)`, the mock adopted the default behaviour, which is to return null.

To fix, just don't mock it `TestClass`!  Construct an instance of it instead, so your `check()` calls will call the actual method shown in your second code block.

Comment: That is a good answer, thank you. I didn't mock the class being tested in other tests though, but couldn't find a way to make function getLong() return values that i want. I've found a workaround for that, now i instantiate this function as BiFunction, mock it in test and then inject it into TestClass instance.

Comment: @George I think there might be another issue if you want/need to call `getLong()`, but have it do something different to what `getLong()` actually does.  I'd suggest asking a question about *that* problem in fact, in case there's a clearer or cleaner way to handle this than your current workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Thumbs Up for the Answer!! @Andrzej 
**Just bringing the bigger picture.** 
In general Unite testing perform to test a small piece of code, usually a method.
So it is expected that the method to be tested is not mocked. So there is the concept of **stubing** i.e stub piece of code which you consider should not be part of this unit test.

So as per the principle `getLong()` which is the dependency on this method represents the similar responsibility or it is playing must part in this functionality. If it is so then it should be **private**. 
If `getLong()` should not bare the responsibilities from this class then it should be part of the other class, hence **Single Responsibility Principle** kicks in.

You can still do it irrespective of these best practices,
you just have to call `thenCallRealMethod()` and to call the `getLong()` from same class you have to **Spy** on the `TestClass` and it will work fine.

But we should keep in Mind **there is a reason Mockito doesn't allow mocking private and static methods**.
Happy Coding !!!